# why Intellij IDEA close file on save and then copy another?

Tags: intellij-idea, go

How can I disable this? the file name be add suffix 201505031440055...

I try to rename it, but IDEA will create another

[image]

thx

Comment: Intellij IDEA is V14.1.2 Community Edition for Mac

Comment: I've never had this happen, can you please provide some more details on when this is happening or what are the steps to reproduce?

Comment: when I use COMMAND+S to save file, the file will be closed auto, and then IEDA create another with suffix

Answer (score 0):

fixed by install Intellij IDEA again, not Community Edition